# MS Access - MSys Objects has orphaned query SQL for renamed form

Tags: ms-access

In a Microsoft Access database I inherited, I had a form called frm_LabList. The record source was a Select statement. I renamed the form to frmLabour and everything continues to work well.

Today, I discovered that there is a record in MSysObjects that still holds the Select statement referring to the old form name. There is also a record that holds the Select statement that refers to the new form name.

Two questions:

1. Will this orphaned query record in MSysObjects cause a problem?
2. Is there a way to clear out these orphaned records?

I've compacted and repaired but the orphaned record still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usual behavior.

**First question:** No, I've noticed these a lot (the query names tend to start with `~sq_f`, and refer to an old version of your form). I don't think the storage space it takes up is relevant. I tend to write code to not show these when making a list of all queries, but never had any further issues with them

**Second question:** Yes, with some simple VBA you can delete these. Just execute the following line through the immediate window:  `CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "~sq_ffrm_LabList"`.

Note that when deleting the queries behind normal forms, they just get recreated as soon as the form opens.

The following code deletes all form queries, *run at your own risk!* (haven't noticed any issues myself after running it, as far as I know the SQL is stored in the `Form.Recordsource` property, but the query object still stores things such as layout when using the query builder on the `Form.Recordsource` property)

```
Public Sub DeleteFormQueries()
    Dim qdf As Object
    For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        If qdf.Name Like "~sq_f*" Then
            CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdf.Name
        End If
    Next qdf
End Sub
```